# Files Upload is not Working for Community Profiles

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, permissions

I have created one file upload component page and using that page in the community portal but when I'm uploading a file a file its not working.

If I'm doing the same with a console app, then it is working. So I think some permission issues I have because its working for system admin profile but not for community profile.

Can Anyone have some Idea on this? what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: Hi there, I am facing the same issue.. Can you please help me if you found out any way to allow the community user upload file using lightning:fileUpload tag

Comment: This question is similar to an existing post which has several useful answers. here is the link, please check if the answers can help:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222577/what-are-permissions-are-needed-to-upload-a-file-via-a-public-salesforce-communi